# How to transform PointCloud2 with TF?

Tags: ros, geometry, sensor-msgs, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm writing a small node aggregating data from a Kinect sensor (PointCloud2) taken from different angle of view. I therefore use the tf library to transform all images in the /world frame before aggregating them with the pcl lib.

After looking through tf API doc, I found the TransformListener::transformPointCloud function to tranform PointCloud messages but nothing to transform PointCloud2 messages. I am therefore using a code like this:

`sensor_msgs::convertPointCloud2ToPointCloud(pc2SensorFrame,pcSensorFrame) TfListener.transformPointCloud("/world", pcSensorFrame, pcWorldFrame); sensor_msgs::convertPointCloudToPointCloud2(pcWorldFrame,pc2WorldFrame) pcl::fromROSMsg(pc2WorldFrame,pclCloud);`

It seems to work but I was wondering if there was a more direct way to transform PointCloud2 with tf avoiding the conversion in PointCloud.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9103/how-to-transform-pointcloud2-with-tf?/) by [Captain](https://answers.ros.org/users/112/captain/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2011-02-16

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess you are looking for the pcl_ros package. It contains functions to do exactly what you want. Have a look here:

http://docs.ros.org/api/pcl_ros/html/namespacepcl__ros.html

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2011-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 11

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lahiruherath](https://answers.ros.org/users/32349/lahiruherath/) on 2017-11-09**:
Why is the page not available now? PCL ROS has been taken out or what?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2017-11-09**:
This is a very old link. We've moved the documentation years ago to docs.ros.org It's now at: http://docs.ros.org/api/pcl_ros/html/namespacepcl__ros.html In the future if you're looking for docs visit the wiki page for a package eg http://wiki.ros.org/pcl_ros and click on the Code API link.

**Comment by [lahiruherath](https://answers.ros.org/users/32349/lahiruherath/) on 2017-11-09**:
Thanks :). Managed to get this done using tf2. Had to do some blind manipulations since i was using python

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can transform using the tf2_sensor_msgs (both C++ and Python interface, since at least Indigo):

```
#include <tf2_sensor_msgs/tf2_sensor_msgs.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/TransformStamped.h>

const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2 cloud_in, cloud_out;
const geometry_msgs::TransformStamped transform;
// TODO load everything
tf2::doTransform (cloud_in, cloud_out, transform);
```

Or in Python:

```
from tf2_sensor_msgs.tf2_sensor_msgs import do_transform_cloud
cloud_out = do_transform_cloud(cloud_in, transform)
```

Please note that all of these transform functions only transform the `x,y,z` channel. If your pointcloud contains viewpoints or normals, you'd have to transform them yourself.

---

Originally posted by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) with karma: 1366 on 2015-08-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2015-08-14**:
I get a `tf2_sensor_msgs.py` `cannot import name read_cloud` error in Indigo.  Is the transform the return value of a `lookupTransform`?

**Comment by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) on 2015-08-17**:
You're right, @lucasw, there seems to be a bug in `do_transform_cloud`. I've reported it here: https://github.com/ros/geometry_experimental/issues/121 .

**Comment by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) on 2015-08-17**:
Until the bug gets fixed, you can manually copy&paste the code of the method's body and change `read_cloud` to `read_points`. The method body is here: https://github.com/ros/geometry_experimental/blob/jade-devel/tf2_sensor_msgs/src/tf2_sensor_msgs/tf2_sensor_msgs.py#L52

**Comment by [Azergoo](https://answers.ros.org/users/34694/azergoo/) on 2018-07-10**:
Have anyone got this to work? Seems to be deprecated.

**Comment by [rosNewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/50638/rosnewbie/) on 2020-01-02**:
I tried using this method (in python) but it somehow doesn't work as expected. That's why I used a transformation with 0 translation and 0 rotation to test, but it nevertheless changes my pointcloud. Anyone expericened something like this?

**Comment by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) on 2020-07-15**:
I keep getting compilation errors when trying to include `tf2_sensor_msgs.h` Is is this code depreciated?

**Comment by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) on 2020-07-16**:
No, the code still works great. You have to add a build dependency on tf2_sensor_msgs to your CMakeLists.txt and package.xml (and you have to actually install the package, e.g. ros-melodic-tf2-sensor-msgs).

**Comment by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) on 2020-07-16**:
Ah, the bit I was missing is that the include needs to be `#include <tf2_sensor_msgs/tf2_sensor_msgs.h>` Now it works

**Comment by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) on 2020-07-16**:
Ah, the bit I was missing is that the include needs to be `#include <tf2_sensor_msgs/tf2_sensor_msgs.h>`

**Comment by [peci1](https://answers.ros.org/users/7736/peci1/) on 2020-07-16**:
You're right! Thanks, I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a simple code to transform scan point cloud to base link. Use a separate script for    `class laser_to_points2d:` for ease of use.

```
from math import sin, cos
import tf
import numpy as np
from sensor_msgs.msg import PointCloud
from geometry_msgs.msg import Point32

 class laser_to_points2d:
    def __init__(self,):
        self.base_link_point2d=PointCloud()
        self.base_link_point2d.header.frame_id = "base_link" 

    def update(self,scandata,angle_min,angle_max,angle_increment):
        self.base_link_point2d.points=[]
        self.base_link_point2d.channels=[]

        for i in xrange(len(scandata)):     
            angle=angle_min+i*angle_increment
            if not math.isnan(scandata[i]):
                r=scandata[i]
            else:r=0.0 

            px=float(r)*cos(angle)
            py=float(r)*sin(angle)
            self.base_link_point2d.points.append(Point32(px,py, 0.0))
            self.base_link_point2d.channels.append(0)# add some information if needed
```

You need to listen to the transformation for Odom to base_link and subscribe the scan topic

```
import rospy
import roslib
from sensor_msgs.msg import LaserScan
import tf
from file_name_your_ class _laser_to_points2d import laser_to_points2d

def scanCb(msg):
    py,px=[],[]
    scandata=msg.ranges
    angle_min=msg.angle_min
    angle_max=msg.angle_max
    angle_increment=msg.angle_increment
    range_min=msg.range_min
    range_max=msg.range_max
    points2d.update(scandata,angle_min,angle_max,angle_increment)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    rospy.init_node('main', anonymous=True) #make node  
    rospy.Subscriber("/scan", LaserScan, scanCb,queue_size = 1) 
    rate = rospy.Rate(5) # 5hz         
    points2d=laser_to_points2d()
    listener = tf.TransformListener()           
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        
        listener.waitForTransform("/base_link", "/odom", rospy.Time(0),rospy.Duration(1.0))     
        p=listener.transformPointCloud("odom",points2d.base_link_point2d)   
        rate.sleep()
```

---

Originally posted by [Gayan Brahmanage](https://answers.ros.org/users/26769/gayan-brahmanage/) with karma: 929 on 2017-07-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-07-13**:
As is, this won't run. You'll need to indent everything after the `if __name__ == "__main__":`

**Comment by [Mekateng](https://answers.ros.org/users/30895/mekateng/) on 2017-08-11**:
Hi Gayan,
I first created named laserTF package. After that I  created two python files named lasertf.py and laserTransform.py in the packaged src file I created. I pasted the code above into the lasertf file and the code below into the laserTransform file.

**Comment by [Mekateng](https://answers.ros.org/users/30895/mekateng/) on 2017-08-11**:
And file name your class at the time I wrote lasertf. But ı got an error like below
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/ahmet/catkin_ws/src/laserTF/src/laserTransform.py", line 2, in 
import rospy
....
Can I learn the reason for this ?

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-11**:
@Mekateng, you should create a new question and reference this question.

**Comment by [Mekateng](https://answers.ros.org/users/30895/mekateng/) on 2017-08-11**:
I couldn't create new question . Mr foote is closing my questions.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-11**:
Just follow the guidelines as @tfoote said and they won't get closed.

**Comment by [Mekateng](https://answers.ros.org/users/30895/mekateng/) on 2017-08-11**:
ı had asked my question to Gayan. but if you want to reply my question ,ı am looking forward to wait your answer bro

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-11**:
I will, just ask a new question. Comments aren't the place for asking and answering new questions.

**Comment by [Mekateng](https://answers.ros.org/users/30895/mekateng/) on 2017-08-11**:
I'm trying to code Gayan wrote. Do not I have to ask him about the problem I'm having? I'm sure a new question will not answer anyone. It's always been so until now.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-11**:
This is the way it works. Create a new question according to [the guidelines](http://wiki.ros.org/Support#Guidelines_for_asking_a_question_.28Please_read_before_posting.29) and reference this question/answer with the code and your terminal output in the question. People will do their best to answer.

**Comment by [Mekateng](https://answers.ros.org/users/30895/mekateng/) on 2017-08-12**:
okey Mr. jayess . I will do what you say now

**Comment by [Gayan Brahmanage](https://answers.ros.org/users/26769/gayan-brahmanage/) on 2017-12-06**:
Hi Mek,
You need to publish tf while this script is running. Otherwise, it will be terminated after the timeout. Hope this will help you. Sorry for the delayed reply!!!

**Comment by [Mekateng](https://answers.ros.org/users/30895/mekateng/) on 2017-12-07**:
Thank you Mr. Gayan. I want to ask one more question. I can obtain 3d point cloud data but ı want to determine the nearest object angle and distance when scanning. How can I do this? Please help me this situation

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-12-07**:
@Mekateng please create a new question to ask a question. Comments aren't the appropriate place to do that.